# Observablecollection from Query

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin

I am working to implement a local SQLite DB in my app and my Observablecollection seems to return empty when it should have a list of image names like "image1.png","image2.png","image3.png" etc. The Model is as follows:

```
public class ImageDB
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public string ImageSource { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

And I am essentially trying to fill an Oberservablecollection like so:

```
var myList = await App.Database.GetChinsAsync();
FeaturesChangerSource = new ObservableCollection<string>(myList.Select(x => 
x.ImageSource.ToString()).ToList());
```

Using this method:

```
public Task<List<ImageDB>> GetChinsAsync()
    {
return database.QueryAsync<ImageDB>("SELECT * FROM tImages WHERE Description 
LIKE '%chin%'");
    }
```

Property Change notification:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _featuresChangerSource;
public ObservableCollection<string> FeaturesChangerSource
{
    get { return _featuresChangerSource; }
    set { _featuresChangerSource = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

Any insight as to why the Observablecollection is empty?

Comment: 1)check that the query is actually return data. 2) check the conversion between the query result and List in your method.

Comment: 3) Check if the property you expose the OC in also supports Change Notification. See my answer here for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47984688/3346583

Comment: 1)  the query in DB Browser for SQLite returns data. 2) unsure as to whether the conversion is completely correct. not sure how to check to verify 3) I do have a Change Notification, as I have the same OC further into the switch statement that are manually filled and update correctly: 
FeaturesChangerSource = new ObservableCollection<string>
  {"nose1.png", "nose2.png", "nose3.png", "nose4.png","nose5.png","nose6.png" };